# How to identify column values with specific condition for values in other two column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, identify IDs which leave 5 star on one app and 1 star on another and vice versa.
Data frame has 1,050,000 rows.

```
           ID  Star  App_Name
0    41a-Z451     5         A
1    40591758     5         A
2    41128444     5         R
3    40537354     2         H
4    41a-Z451     1         B
5    40552356     1         I
6    413lll95     4         K
7    40htt506     5         A
8    41322993     3         C
9    414ju239     4         D
```

Output: (something like below)

```
           ID  Star  App_Name    User0n1
0    41a-Z451     5         A          1
1    40591758     5         A          0
2    41128444     5         R          0
3    40537354     2         H          0
4    41a-Z451     1         B          1
5    40552356     1         I          0
6    413lll95     4         K          0
7    40htt506     5         A          0
8    41322993     3         C          0
9    414ju239     4         D          0
```

Comment: Your input is not really helpful, you only have a single user who rated two apps. Can you provide a more generic input (valid multi-rating, etc.)? And explicit the conditions you want to use.

Comment: Modified, added a column with app names. Not sure if this would help. I only want that one user who gave 1 star to one app and 5 to another.

Comment: added solution for match both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I modified a bit the input to have one more user with multiple votes.

*NB. the app column shouldn't matter in the computation as a user can (usually) only vote once per app, thus the apps are necessarily unique per user.*

If you strictly want to identify users that voted both a 5 and a 1, you can use `np.ptp` that will give you `4` in such case:

```
import numpy as np
df['Weird_User'] = df.groupby('ID')['Star'].transform(np.ptp).eq(4).astype(int)
```

If you specifically want to match all values from a list of conditions:

```
match = [1, 5]
df['Weird_User'] = (df.groupby('ID')['Star']
                      .transform(lambda x: all(v in x.values for v in match))
                      .astype(int)
                    )
```

output:

```
         ID  Star  Weird_User
0  41a-Z451     5           1
1  40591758     5           0
2  41128444     5           0
3  41128444     2           0
4  41a-Z451     1           1
5  40552356     1           0
6  41128444     4           0
7  40htt506     5           0
8  41322993     3           0
9  414ju239     4           0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare values of `Star` per groups converted to `set`s:

```
df['Weird_User'] = (df.groupby('ID')['Star']
                      .transform(lambda x: set(x) == set({1,5})).astype(int))
print (df)
     ID  Star App_Name  Weird_User
0  41a-Z451     5        A           1
1  40591758     5        A           0
2  41128444     5        R           0
3  40537354     2        H           0
4  41a-Z451     1        B           1
5  40552356     1        I           0
6  413lll95     4        K           0
7  40htt506     5        A           0
8  41322993     3        C           0
9  414ju239     4        D           0
```

Comment: Hi, do we need App_Name? Since the app column shouldn't matter in the computation as a user can only vote once per app, thus the apps are necessarily unique per user. Your code breaks when I remove it.

Comment: @Mystic - answer is edited.